# Sendmail uninstallation issues

Tags: debian, sendmail

Something went wrong with my sendmail installation so I uninstalled it with `--purge`. I still see the `/etc/init.d/sendmail` script and `/etc/mail` is full of sendmail files (.db, aliases, etc). Is there any way I can figure out what files I do have to delete manually ? also the users I have to delete/create in order to make it work ?

Comment: Perhaps some additional details would help: What specific version of Debian?  What specific version of sendmail? How did you originally install it?

Answer (score 0):

You run `dpkg -l | grep sendmail` and you *--purge* the rest of the relevant packages.

Comment: I deleted files that I believed were part of sendmail and finally installed postfix.